# Is it possible to import similarly named exports from multiple modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, create-react-app

Let's say I have a module `A` and `B` both of which export:

```
export const Name = 'Something'
```

Currently the only working solution is to manually import `Name` from each module:

```
import { Name } from 'A'
// or
import { Name } from 'B'
```

But is it possible to import all exported `Name` into a list of some sort? For example:

```
const Names = import 'all Name from all modules'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case u need both exports in the same file, you can use `as` to assign an alias to them. Example:

```
import { Name as AName } from 'A'
import { Name as BName } from 'B'
```